# Exception: Duplicate OG Action -- These exact parameters have been used to publish a previous action with ID

Tags: facebook-opengraph, restfb

We are facing below exception, while create multiple ads for "Mobile App install"
**Marked for retry: Received Facebook error response of type Exception: Duplicate OG Action -- These exact parameters have been used to publish a previous action with ID**

Comment: This was a known issue, but should be fixed now. Please check this bug for details - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/469662739757293